# How to replace only NaN values in a column, with a specific function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
article_id          title
NaN                 title_1
NaN                 title_2
NaN                 title_3
'202102011404103'   title_4
'202102011404104'   title_5
NaN                 title_6
```

I would like to apply something like this code, to NaN values in article_id column:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y%m%d%H%M")
df['article_id'] = [int(date + str("0"*(3-len(str(i)))) + str(i)) + 1 for i, k in df.reset_index().iterrows()]
```

**Instead of `datetime.now()** I would like to start the 1st january. I would like to have a value for the variable date = '202101011348' for example

And in final result I would like to have the same length as row 4 and 5 for article_id column and start to a precise date (202101011348)

I tought doing this:

```
df[df['article_id'].isna()]
```

And then apply the code above.

Expected output:

```
article_id          title
'202101011404106'   title_1
'202101011404107'   title_2
'202101011404108'   title_3
'202102011404103'   title_4
'202102011404104'   title_5
'202101011404109'   title_6
```

But how to apply this directly to the df, only to NaN values in the article_id column ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` to achieve your goal.

Here I'm applying the `now()` function to `NaN` but it can be any method you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "article_id": [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, "202101011212", "202101011313"], 
    "title": ["title_1", "title_2", "title_3", "title_4", "title_5"]
})

|------------------------------------------|
|   | article_id                 | title   |
|---|----------------------------|---------|
| 0 | NaN                        | title_1 |
| 1 | NaN                        | title_2 |
| 2 | NaN                        | title_3 |
| 3 | 202101011212               | title_4 |
| 4 | 202101011313               | title_5 |
|------------------------------------------|

df["article_id"] = df3["article_id"].apply(lambda x: datetime.now() if pd.isna(x) else x)

|------------------------------------------|
|   | article_id                 | title   |
|---|----------------------------|---------|
| 0 | 2021-02-03 13:16:29.438263 | title_1 |
| 1 | 2021-02-03 13:16:29.438269 |title_2  |
| 2 | 2021-02-03 13:16:29.438270 |title_3  |
| 3 | 202101011212               |title_4  |
| 4 | 202101011313               | title_5 |
|------------------------------------------|
```